# strict weak ordering confusion

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, set, strict-weak-ordering

I am confused about strict weak ordering and how to use it when defining operator<. I have a couple of structs:

```
struct Plane
{
    std::string name;

    int xrudder;
    int yrudder;

    int wingwidgets;

    bool hasLegacyEngine;
};


struct Airport
{
    bool securityCheck;
    unsigned __int64 capacity;

    std::vector<Plane> planes;
};
```

and I want to create a `std::set` of Airports. I need to define operator< which uses strict weak ordering but I don't know exactly what that means and/or how to do it.

```
struct cmpless
{
bool operator()(const Airport& left, const Airport& right)
    {
        //?
    }
}; 

std::set<Airport, cmpless> airportSet;
```

**It doesn't make sense that one airport is "less than" another.** It only makes sense if the airports are equal based on their stats.

How can I be sure that my definition of operator< will follow strict weak ordering? How do I begin to think about defining `operator<` in a situation like this?

An example with an explanation would be great if possible!

Comment: I see that you give every plane a name, but your airports don't have any names. If you give the airports a name you can use a lexical string comparison, since it defines a strict weak ordering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it "doesn't make sense" for one `Airport` to come before another `Airport` then the use of `std::set<Airport>` doesn't make sense, either. This container leverages the order amount elements to locate objects in `O(log(n))` operations (where `n` is the size of the container). If you can identify object by identity only, the best complexity you can achieve is `O(n)`. You can use a combination of `std::find()` or `std::find_if()` and one of the sequence containers, e.g., `std::vector<Airport>` or `std::deque<Airport>`.

Since you don't need to define an order in terms of `operator<()`, it may be reasonable to just bring the `Airport`s into some order for the purpose of locating them in a `std::set<Airport>` which is done by using a different comparison function object than `std::less<Airport>`. The attribute you currently have in your `Airport` object don't really look like suitable keys, though. In fact, they all look as if they would be mutable, i.e., you probably wouldn't want a `std::set<Airport>` anyway because you can't modify the elements in an `std::set<T>` (well, at least, you shouldn't; yes, I realize that you can play tricks with `mutable` but this is bound to break the order of the elements).

Based on this, I'd recommend to use a `std::map<std:string, Airport>`: the `std::string` is used to identify the airport, e.g., using the airport codes like `"JFK"` for the John F. Kennedy Airport in New York or `"LHR"` for London Heathrow. Conveniently, there is already a strict weak order defined on strings.

That said, to define a [strict weak order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) on a set of objects `O`, you need to a binary relation `r(x, y)` such that the following conditions hold for elements `x`, `y`, and `z` from `O`:

- irreflexive: `r(x, x) == false`
- asymmetric: `r(x, y) == true` implies `r(y, x) == false`
- transitive:  `r(x, y) == true` and `r(y, z) == true` implies `r(x, z) == true`
- incomparability: `r(x, y) == false` and `r(y, x) == false` and `r(y, z) == false` and `r(z, y) == false` implies `r(x, z) == false` and `r(z, x) == false`

The first three should be simple enough. The last one is a bit odd at first but actually not that hard either: The basic idea is that the relation doesn't entirely order element but groups them into equivalent classes. If you think of the relation `r` to be "smaller than" it just says that if neither `x` is smaller than `y` nor `y` is smaller than `x`, then `x` and `y` are equivalent. The incomparable elements are just equivalent.

The standard containers work with a strict weak order but, e.g., `std::set<T>` and `std::map<K, V>` keep just one version of equivalent keys. It is nice that this is sufficient but it is often simpler to just use a total order which is a strict weak order where for each pair of element `x` and `y` either `r(x, y) == true` or `r(y, x) == true` (but, due to the asymmetry not both).

Comment: 'If you can identify object by identity only, the best complexity you can achieve is O(n)', actually, you could use a hash-based container to do better

Comment: How does a hash help you if your test is `is_identical(x, y)`? The statement is rather precise: You can ask if the two objects are identical, not more not less. If there are other properties, you can possibly do better. Given that the attributes seem to be mutable, this seems to be as good as it gets, though, as any hash value would change.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking more about what you can do if you can't order, not if all you can do is test identity.

Comment: There is some ambiguous/misleading text the end of the first paragraph: "If you can identify object by identity only, the best complexity you can achieve is O(n)."  Given the context of this question, I interpret "if you can identify an object by identity only" to mean "if you have == but no operator<".  So that doesn't preclude having *or writing* a hash function (which is almost always possible) in which case the best complexity you can achieve is actually O(1)  (*better* than std::set!), by using a hash map (e.g. std::unordered_set).

Comment: It makes perfect sense to have a "set" of airports. Just not an ordered set like `sdt::set`. If they need to be uniquely identified based on their properties you should use an `std:unordered_set`. This simply requires a hash function and equality operator are completely valid for objects like airports.

Comment: I always find the last one difficult to understand but your *"the incomparable elements are just equivalent"* explains this beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Found a nice solution on [musingstudio blog](https://musingstudio.com/2013/02/25/implementing-operator-for-strict-weak-ordering/) and thought I share it here for the next one in need (even if Dietmar may be right that a map is not appropriate):

```
bool operator <(const T& rhs) const
{
  if (a < rhs.a)
    return true;
  else if (rhs.a < a)
    return false;

  if (b < rhs.b)
    return true;
  else if (rhs.b < b)
    return false;

  // repeat for all child elements c, d, e etc
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something akin to a lexiographical order if every member has `<` defined:

```
   struct cmpless
    {
    bool operator()(const Airport& left, const Airport& right)
        {
            return
              left.securityCheck < right.securityCheck
              || ((left.securityCheck == right.securityCheck
                   && left.capacity < right.capacity)
                  || (left.capacity == right.capacity
                      && left.planes < right.planes));
        }
    };
```

Comment: I may be mistaken--parsing boolean expressions is not my strongest point--but I think your parentheses should read: `return
              left.securityCheck < right.securityCheck
              || (left.securityCheck == right.securityCheck
                   && (left.capacity < right.capacity
                  || (left.capacity == right.capacity
                      && left.planes < right.planes)));`

Comment: I think that dhavenith may be right about the parentheses but I'm not sure. Can you double check your answer with his suggestion and let me know what you think?